# Dual Monitor on Windows causing calibration error on tablet (input device) when using Windows Journal

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, tablet, input-device

Recently, I got a dual monitor set up for my desktop running on Windows 7.

However, this causes some problems with my tablet input-device in certain applications. I use Windows Journal very frequently for taking notes before I had my dual monitor setup. After having this dual monitor set up, there seems to have some calibration error with my tablet in Windows Journal.

I can write with the pen tool in Windows Journal on my tablet without problem. However, when I try to use the eraser tool or the lasso tool with my tablet pen in Windows Journal, there seems to have some offset error. The eraser and lasso tool activates on about 200pixels to left of where I am pointing on my tablet.

When I use my mouse instead of my tablet with the eraser and lasso tool in Windows Journal, it works fine. My tablet also seems to work fine in other applications like Photoshop. It only happens in certain applications. Removing my dual set up solves the problem but this definitely isn't a very sensible solution.

What is wrong with my dual monitor set up that causes my tablet to loose its calibration and not working in certain applications like Windows Journal? How can I fix this problem?

Comment: This seems more like a problem with the software then anything.  My suggestion is use software that doesn't have these problems or unplug the monitor when you want to use them.

Answer (score 0):

As Ramhound says: There's nothing wrong with your Setup: it's rather the Software you use, in that Case Windows Journal. l just got myself a wacom bamboo and discovered the exact same thing in Windows Journal on my dual-Monitor Setup.

Comment: Can you expand on this answer?

Comment: well, what do You wanna know? I have the same Offset-Problem with The Eraser Tool in Windows Journal as described above.